# How to add custom soap header in ASMX web service response

Tags: soap, asmx

I wrote a simple web service in ASMX and i want to add a custom header in RESPONSE. 
below is the code.

```
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        public List<CustomerInfo> VerifyCustomerInfo(string Id, string IdType, Char InquiredParty, IndividualPartyAttributes IndividualPartyAttributes, string NonIndividualName, AccountQuery accountQuery)
        {

            List<CustomerInfo> ciList = new List<CustomerInfo>();
            string replycode = "E9999999";
            CustomerInfo customer = new CustomerInfo();
            customer.IsBankCustomer = true;
            customer.CustomerNumber = "111";
            ciList.Add(customer);

            // TODO: add code here to send replyCode ("E9999999") as custom header in response XML.

            return ciList;
        }
    }
```

Comment: i tried following code but it does not add any header.                         HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("ReplyCode", replycode);

Answer (score 0):

If you mean SOAP Header then add below attribute on your WebService method:

```
[SoapHeader("ABC", Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.Out)]
```

ABC is the custom class.

```
[XmlRoot("ABC", Namespace = "")]
public class ABC : SoapHeader
```